# Backbone write to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, backbone.js

Here is a link to the code on github

https://github.com/dkhuntrods/Wedding-Seating-Planner-Prototype

I have a problem with writing the change of states. When something is moved

on canvas all, changes should be saved to json files. Here is a screen capture of the problem

[image: Problem Picture]

Basically, I think it cannot locate `tables.json/table1` because there is no such

file.  However, I cannot seem to understand the code.

Comment: Are you using a backbone collection or backbone model?

Comment: Backbone model i think ,Im new to all this..The probel is it wont update json file with new values ..it seems to be targeting the wrong file....but I can not seem to change it

Comment: Please make your question clearer. Very few people are going to bother to check your project out or browse the code on github. Try to summarise the problem here with some code illustrating the problem

Comment: This project appears to belong to a proprietary service. Unless you have access to their RESTful API, I sincerely doubt you'll be able to make HTTP POST requests and get the desired outcome.